# Is this a case of suitable ellipsis, or grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, ellipses

Is the following sentence considered correct or acceptable?

> The crash cart was originally designed and patented by ECRI Institute founder, Joel J. Nobel, M.D., while a surgical resident at Philadelphia's Pennsylvania Hospital in 1965.

This sounds strange to me. I guess I would have written something like:

> ", while he was a surgical resident..." - or 
>  
>   ", while he worked as a surgical resident..."

I tried thinking of some other examples of this construction, such as:

1. I made hardly any money while busking. (This sounds correct)
2. I made hardly any money while a busker. (Is this correct?)
3. I made hardly any money while I was a busker. (This sounds correct)

Is the sentence in (2) correct or acceptable? What's the explanation behind it? I'm tempted to say that the omission of (I was) is a case of ellipsis, but I'm not sure if this is the case, as the verb (was) is not mentioned anywhere previously. The sentence starts "I made..." and then the part after the "while" is "I was". However this is also the case in:

> I drove home while drunk. (This seems fine)
>   I drove home while I was drunk.
>  
>   I drove home while being drunk.

Omitting the "I was" seems fine even though the verb "was" isn't mentioned previously.

Comment: The irritation that you sense might be due to the fact that in your examples the omitted verb is located in a context where the subject is co-referential, which does not hold for the example in your OP.

Comment: Wherever you mentioned 'sounds fine' sound find to me too. Of the last three examples, you could also consider 1) I drove home (being) drunk. 3) I drove home (while) being drunk.

Comment: I agree with you. The sentence, if understood literally, suggests that the cart was a resident at the hospital.

Comment: @Nico My example number 2, is the verb coreferential? "I made hardly any money while a busker"? This still sounds strange to me.

Comment: To me, this sentence is hardly acceptable.